# Its possible Reverse mysql fetch array with out ORDER By clauses?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, arraylist

Its possible to reverse `mysql_fetch_array` values,without using `ORDER BY` clauses in `SELECT` query?

Comment: Wut? Why without order by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is just to reverse the returned array, then you can use `array_reverse`:

```
array_reverse($array);
```

You can find more information [at the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-reverse.php)

Answer (score 0):

When you do a select statement, you can never be certin of the order of items returned.  So in order to be certain, you must use a order by clause.  If you want a reverse order, do

```
ORDER BY columnA DESC
```

Most of the time, most databases will return things, without an order by in the order that rows were added, but it is non-deterministic.